# WCF Not Binding to TCP Port (checking via netstat -a)

Tags: vb.net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, tcp

Okay, I'll try to make this as straight forward as possible.  I'm using VB.Net in VS2010, I'm attempting to self-host a WCF service. (It's actually in a windows service, but I'm trying to do this via a simple console app.  Below is the code in question, the TCP/IP addresses are injected directly here.  The WCF service itself is simply a renamed DEFAULT new WCF service project.

```
Dim host As New ServiceHost(GetType(TestService))

Dim tcpb As New NetTcpBinding()
tcpb.PortSharingEnabled = True
host.AddServiceEndpoint( _
    GetType(ITestService), _
    tcpb, _
    "net.tcp://localhost:62020/TestWcfService/" _
)

host.Open()

Console.ReadKey(True)

host.Close()
```

I don't think I can make this much simpler.. is there something special I need to do to get the port to actually bind?  when I run `netstat -a` it doesn't show a listening port on 62020  I am really at my whits end on this.

Background: I have another WCF service I'm trying to migrate out of IIS, and into a separate server running in a Windows Service.  The WCF service will only be accessed internally.  I've been having numerous issues in getting that migrated, so trying to get a simple service to bind, and have a client (website) access it.  The other WCF is binding (different port) fine, but having communications errors.  There is a literal ****-ton of stuff out there, and very little really fits my needs, and I'm having a lot of trouble getting anything working with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the exact same problem when testing a new service. Turns out I had simply forgot to mark the service interface with the [ServiceContract] attribute. I guess WCF didn't bother with creating an endpoint since no service contracts were found.

Would have been nice with an error message since I can't imagine anyone wanting to open a ServiceHost without at least one contract being implemented, but I suspect this only happens when you are using simplified configuration in .NET 4.

Comment: Nope... the interface specifies <ServiceContract()> ... :/  good point though.

Comment: Turned out to be a similar issue... went around and added the endpoint uri's separately from the appropriate bindings... this is being done in code currently, but will be adjusting to use a config-based setup (service/client settings)... the client proxies will still be codified, as the backend will be running on multiple machines (depending on the user/session).